# How to use $elemMatch on aggregate's projection?

Tags: mongodb, projection

This is my object:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fdcb6796cb9b9aa86f05b9"), "list" : [ "a", "b" ], "complist" : [ { "a" : "a", "b" : "b" }, { "a" : "c", "b" : "d" } ] }
```

And this is what I want to accomplish: check if "list" contains a certain element and get only the field "a" from the objects on "complist" while reading the document regardless of any of these values. I'm building a forum system, this is the query that will return the details of a forum. I need to read the forum information while knowing if the user is in the forum's white list.

With a find I can use the query

```
db.itens.find({},{list:{$elemMatch:{$in:["a"]}}})
```

to get only the first element that matches a certain value. This way I can just check if the returned array is not empty and I know if "list" contains the value I'm looking for. I can't do it on the query because I want the document regardless of it containing the value I'm looking for in the "list" value. I need the document AND know if "list" has a certain value.

With an aggregate I can use the query

```
db.itens.aggregate({$project:{"complist.a":1}})
```

to read only the field "a" of the objects contained in complist. This is going to get the forum's threads basic information, I don't want all the information of the threads, just a couple of things.

But when I try to use the query

```
db.itens.aggregate({$project:{"complist.b":1,list:{$elemMatch:{$in:["a"]}}}})
```

to try and do both, it throws me an error saying the operator $elemMatch is not valid.

Am I doing something wrong here with the $elemMatch in aggregate? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -19, accepted):

Well, it happens you can use "array.field" on a find's projection block.

```
 db.itens.find({},{"complist.b":1,list:{$elemMatch:{$in:["a"]}}})
```

did what I needed.

Comment: question was about aggregation, not find

Comment: Question is about the Aggregation not the find.

Answer (score 34):

Quite on old question but literally none of the proposed answers are good.

---

**TLDR**:

You can't use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage. but you can achieve the same result using other aggregation operators like [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter).

```
db.itens.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            compList: {
               $filter: {
                input: "$complist",
                as: "item",
                cond: {$eq: ["$$item.a", 1]}
               }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

And if you want just the first item from the array that matches the condition similarly to what [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) does you can incorporate [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)

---

**In Depth Explanation**:

First let's understand [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is a query expressions while also this [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) version of it exists this refers to a query projection and not [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) aggregation stage.

So what? what does this have to do with anything? well a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage has certain input structure it can have while the one we want to use is:

> <field>: <expression>

What is a valid [expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions)?

> Expressions can include field paths, literals, system variables, expression objects, and expression operators. Expressions can be nested.

So we want to use an [expression operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#operator-expressions), but as you can see from the doc's `$elemMatch` is not part of it. hence it's not a valid expression to be used in an aggregation `$project` stage.

Comment: `Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.`

Comment: i just forgot to add the field name. i edited it in

Answer (score 17):

For some reason $elemMatch doesn't work in aggregations. You need to use the new $filter operator in Mongo 3.2. See https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Answer (score 15):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47825790/aggregate-documents-where-objects-in-array-matches-multiple-conditions/) maybe help.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({
    "$match": {
        "complist": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "a": "a"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: are you using mongoosejs to access mongo db?

Comment: This works, it wasn't working the first time because if there is a path like "complist.sub.path" should drop the "complist" so that it's there is only "sub.path" below.

Comment: I didn't find a way to get the index of the array in this method, so if you want to do extra manipulations later in the Aggregate, then you better go for the full $unwind way, or use $project like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, the simplest solution is to just $unwind your array, then $match the appropriate documents. You can wind-up the appropriate documents again using $group and $push.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is old, here is my contribution for November 2017.

I had similar problem and doing two consecutive match operations worked for me. The code below is a subset of my whole code and I changed elements names, so it's not tested. Anyway this should point you in the right direction.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": "ID1"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$sub_collection"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "sub_collection.field_I_want_to_match": "value"
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

For aggregations simply use `$expr`:

```js
db.items.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
           "$expr": {"$in": ["a", "$list"]}
        }
    },
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply unwind the document and then group it again by id

```
{ $unwind: "$yourarray" },
{
  $match: {
    "field": { $gt: 1 }
  },
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id"
  }
},
```