# Aggregate documents where objects in array matches multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents similar to such:

```json
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxx"),
    "item": [
        { "property": ["attr1", "+1"] },
        { "property": ["attr2", "-1"] }
    ]
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxy"),
    "item": [
        { "property": ["attr1", "-1"] },
        { "property": ["attr2", "0"] }
    ]
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxz"),
    "item": [
        { "property": ["attr1", "0"] },
        { "property": ["attr2", "+1"] }
    ]
}
```

Preferably using an aggregation pipeline, is there any way to match the document *if and only if* any one of the properties match *more than one* condition?

For example, I want a query where one object in the array matches both of these conditions:

```
("item.property": "attr1") AND ("item.property": /^\+/)
```

That is, a single property where it contains "attr1" and an element that starts with "+".

However, using my current query that looks like this:

```
collection.aggregate(
    { $match:
        { $and: 
            [
                { "item.property": "attr1" },
                { "item.property": /^\+/ }
            ]
        }
    }
```

This would match both the first and last document because both contain a property with "attr1" and an element that stats with "+". However, I do not want this query to match the last document, since the element that starts with "+" does not belong to the same object in the array.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior using the aggregation framework?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the below query with [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to match the array's both values.

Something like

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "item": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "property.0": "attr1",
        "property.1": /^\+/
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Also, you can use [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator if you don't want to reference array index.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "item": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "property": {
          "$all": [
            "attr1",
            /^\+/
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not work with aggregations, right?