# How do I match an array of sub-documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Match documents if a value in an array of sub-documents is greater than some value only if the same document contains a field that is equal to some value

I have a collection that contains documents with an array of sub-documents. This array of sub-documents contains a field that dictates whether or not I can filter the documents in the collection based on another field in the sub-document. This'll make more sense when you see an example of the document.

```
    {  
    "_id":"ObjectId('XXX')",
    "Data":{  
        "A":"",
        "B":"-25.78562 ; 28.35629",
        "C":"165"
    },
    "SubDocuments":[  
        {  
            "_id":"ObjectId('XXX')",
            "Data":{  
                "Value":"XXX",
                "DataFieldId":"B"
            }
        },
        {  
            "_id":"ObjectId('XXX')",
            "Data":{  
                "Value":"",
                "DataFieldId":"A"
            }
        },
        {  
            "_id":"ObjectId('XXX')",
            "Data":{  
                "Value":"105",
                "DataFieldId":"Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I only want to match documents that contain sub-documents with a DataFieldId that is equal to Z but also filter for Values that are greater than 105 only if Data Field Id is equal to Z.

Comment: Can you please share your desired response.

Comment: @Jitendra I'm filtering a list of the documents above based on Data.DataFieldId and Data.Value. It's part of an aggregation pipeline...

Comment: Please confirm that you want "DataFieldId" is equal to "Z" AND  "Value" greater than 105.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        _id:1,
        Data:1,
        filteredSubDocuments: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$SubDocuments",
                as: "subDoc",
                cond: { 
                    $and: [
                        { $eq: ["$$subDoc.Data.DataFieldId", "Z"] },
                        { $gte: ["$$subDoc.Data.Value", 105] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

Resulted response will be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb09659952e3a179190d998"),
    "Data" : {
        "A" : "",
        "B" : "-25.78562 ; 28.35629",
        "C" : "165"
    },
    "filteredSubDocuments" : [
        {
            "_id" : "ObjectId('XXX')",
            "Data" : {
                "Value" : 105,
                "DataFieldId" : "Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jitendra. This isn't what I'm trying to do though. I'd like to filter many of the parent documents (the documents with _id and Data.A, Data.B, Data.C) based on the subdocuments that contain Data.DataFieldId = "Z" and have a Data.Value greater than 105. I'll try and read up a bit more on the filter command and see if I can make it work. Thanks for the help and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: You're welcome @FaiyaazKhan. So you can get the idea from here about MongoDB $filter pipeline stage now as per your requirement you can apply various $and and $or combinations in it to get your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#elemmatch-query) operator on sub-documents, for details you can click on provided link. For your problem you can try below query by using `$elemMatch` which is match simpler than aggregation:

```
    db.collectionName.find({
    "SubDocuments": { 
        $elemMatch: {
            "Data.DataFieldId": "Z" , 
            "Data.Value" : {$gte: 105}  
        } 
    } })
```

Its working fine, I have verified it locally, one modification you required is that you have to put the value of `SubDocuments.Data.Value` as `Number` or `Long` as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @krishna, this isn't what I'm trying to do though. I'd like to filter many of the parent documents (the documents with _id and Data.A, Data.B, Data.C) based on the subdocuments that contain Data.DataFieldId = "Z" and have a Data.Value greater than 105. I'll have a look at the $elemMatch command and see if it's capable of doing what I require. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, even you can try the `$elemMatch` in aggregation pipeline, for reference check the ans of question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47825790/aggregate-documents-where-objects-in-array-matches-multiple-conditions/