# MongoDb projection on array of objects, Get matched object only

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongo document like this

```
{
    "_id": "5b14679e592baa493e0bc208",
    "productCode": "ABC",
    "corridors": [
        {
            "countryNameEn": "Sweden",
            "countryNameFr": "Suède",
            "countryCode": "SE",
            "currencyNameEn": "Swedish Krona",
            "currencyNameFr": "Couronne suédoise",
            "currencyCode": "SEK",
            "corridorLimit": "abc"
        },
        {
            "countryNameEn": "USA",
            "countryNameFr": "Suède",
            "countryCode": "US",
            "currencyNameEn": "USA",
            "currencyNameFr": "Couronne suédoise",
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "corridorLimit": "abc"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "5b14679e592baa493e0bc208",
    "productCode": "XYZ",
    "corridors": [
        {
            "countryNameEn": "Sweden",
            "countryNameFr": "Suède",
            "countryCode": "SE",
            "currencyNameEn": "Swedish Krona",
            "currencyNameFr": "Couronne suédoise",
            "currencyCode": "SEK",
            "corridorLimit": "abc"
        },
        {
            "countryNameEn": "USA",
            "countryNameFr": "Suède",
            "countryCode": "US",
            "currencyNameEn": "USA",
            "currencyNameFr": "Couronne suédoise",
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "corridorLimit": "abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find document whose `productCode` is `ABC` and `currencyCode` is `USD` in corridors array. How can I return only the matching object from `corridors` array like only only object that has `USD` `currencyCode` should come in result and not all array.

I tried running this query `{ productCode: 'ABC', corridors: { $elemMatch: { currencyCode: "USD"}}}`. But it gives me the whole array and not the only matched element.

Comment: refer to this documentation. use $elemmatch in projection https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: I am already using $elemmatch

Comment: use it in projection

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use $elemMatch in $project. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36651117/3215358)

Try the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{

    $match : {"productCode" : "ABC"}
}, 
{
    $unwind : "$corridors"
}, 
{
    $match : { "corridors.currencyCode" : "USD"}
}, 
{
    $group : {
              _id : "$productCode", 
              corridors : {$addToSet : "$corridors"}
}
}]);
```

Outputs:

```
{
    "_id" : "ABC",
    "corridors" : [ 
        {
            "countryNameEn" : "USA",
            "countryNameFr" : "Suède",
            "countryCode" : "US",
            "currencyNameEn" : "USA",
            "currencyNameFr" : "Couronne suédoise",
            "currencyCode" : "USD",
            "corridorLimit" : "abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the result you'll have `_id` instead of `productCode`. If you still want `productCode`, you can just include `$project` in the end.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You "think" wrong then. The [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator has two forms, being one for query and the other ( linked one ) for projection. The question has been long answered though and it's preferable to use `$filter` for "multiple matches" than `$unwind` anyway, for a whole host of reasons. But a standard `$elemMatch` or [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) is all that is needed for a "single" matching result.